# Least-squares constrained to the unit Euclidean sphere

Tags: optimization, least-squares, linear-regression, qcqp

Assume $A\in \mathbb{R}^{t\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^t$. How to solve the following optimization problem in $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|Ax-b\|_2^2\\ \text{subject to} & x^Tx=1\end{array}.$$

---

Thanks for the comments, I already read another question. But in fact, the two answers are not complete. In fact, this is not a convex optimization, so the solution we get may be local maximum or something else.

Can anyone prove that if $x,\lambda$ satisfy
$$A^TAx-A^Tb+\lambda x = 0\\
x^tx=1.$$
This must be a global minimum?

Comment: Why not introduce a Lagrange multiplier?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1256916/339790

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1009403/339790